# Edit SQL table before exporting it to csv file using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to add trailing spaces to each column in a table in sql database using python. The addition of trailing spaces should match with the respective column lengths.

Then I need to export this edited table data to a csv file.

The python code that I used is shown below.

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:30:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]     on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> import csv
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL     SERVER};SERVER=*******;DATABASE=OFAC;UID=****;PWD=******')
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('select top 10 * from ofacdata')
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x00000000033727B0>
>>> row = cursor.fetchall()
>>> column_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
>>> with open(r'OFACDATA1.csv','w') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerow(column_names)
    csv.writer(file).writerows(row)


177
>>>
```

Now I need to Add trailing spaces to columns that will match with the respective column lengths.
Please help me to improve my python code.

```
Input = 

 Name        Age      Country
'qwed'      '23'      'dfdf'
'bgbg'      '24'      'tggt'  

where Name(varchar(7)), Age(varchar(4)), Country(varchar(6))

Expected Output =

  Name          Age         Country
'qwed   '      '23  '      'dfdf  '
'bgbg   '      '24  '      'tggt  '
```

Comment: Each column have different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to get this done.

Using SQL

```
SELECT 
    cast(Name as char(7))   as "Name",cast(age as char(4))   as "Age",cast(Country as char(6))   as "Country"
FROM ofacdata
```

Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
row  =[['abc','25','Canada'],
       ['efg','26','US'],
       ['higj','30','UK']]
df= pd.DataFrame(row)
df.columns = ['Name', 'Age','Country']

format={'Name': '{0: <7}', 'Age': '{0: <4}', 'Country': '{0: <6}'}

for key, value in format.items():
    df[key] = df[key].apply(value.format)
df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what to do if each column have different lengths.

Comment: can you share the input and expected output

Comment: Input and expected output shared.
How to get this output and export this output table to a csv file?